# python function making unrequested changes

Tags: python

I have a function (crout) defined in a file called LU.py and another function defined in a different file (invert.py). The contents of the files are:

LU.py

```
def crout(A,L,U):
  N = len(A)
  add = 0

  #print(L,U)
  for i in range(N):
    print('b',L[i][i])
    U[i][i] = 1 
    print('a',L[i][i])
  #print(L,U)
```

and invert.py

```
import LU

def inverse(A):
  n = len(A)
  B = []
  L = []
  U = []
  for i in range(n):
      row = [0 for j in range(n)]
      B.append(row)
      L.append(row)
      U.append(row)
  LU.crout(A,L,U)
  return B 

M = [[1,2,3],[1,0,1],[2,2,0]]
Mi = inverse(M)

A = [[1,2,3],[1,0,1],[2,2,0]]
L = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
U = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
print('bla')
LU.crout(A,L,U)
```

Notice that I run the function crout two times from the invert file, once from the inverse function and once from outside the function.
Next, I run the invert.py file using python 2.7.6 on an ubuntu linux machine and I get the following output:

```
('b',0)
('a',1)
('b',0)
('a',1)
('b',0)
('a',1)
bla
('b',0)
('a',0)
('b',0)
('a',0)
('b',0)
('a',0)
```

The numbers before the 'bla' which is the call of crout from within inverse, represent the elements of the diagonal in array L. Notice that these values change from 0 ('b') to 1 ('a') as I change the values in U (which off course should not happen!). On the other hand, when I call crout from outside the function inverse the values in L remain unchanged after changing U, which off course is what should happen.

Any ideas about why this is happening would be very much appreciated!

Carlos

Comment: checked python variable scoping rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `inverse`, you `append` the row variable to each of B, L, and U.

```
  for i in range(n):
      row = [0 for j in range(n)]
      B.append(row)
      L.append(row)
      U.append(row)
```

Now each list contains a reference to the same `row` value. changing a value in one of the lists will change the accompanying value in each other one. If this is not the desired behavior, create a new row for each list.

```
  for i in range(n):
      B.append([0 for j in range(n)])
      L.append([0 for j in range(n)])
      U.append([0 for j in range(n)])
```

If this looks a bit inelegant to you, it may be useful to make an independent function for matrix creation logic.

```
def make_square_matrix(size):
    return [[0]*size for b in range(size)]

def inverse(A):
    n = len(A)
    B = make_square_matrix(n)
    L = make_square_matrix(n)
    U = make_square_matrix(n)
    LU.crout(A,L,U)
    return B
```

Comment: Thanks, the scope rules are quite different from C.

Comment: Notice now that, since B is no longer modified when L and U are modified, `inverse` will always return a matrix containing nothing but zeroes. I'm assuming the actual `inverse` function contains more code than what appears in the question, and B eventually gets modified to have more useful values.

Comment: Yes, there is more code, but I just went for the part that made the mistake.